# Alternate method of VEShape.GetIconAnchor Method in Google Map V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Any idea what is the alternate of VEShape.GetIconAnchor Method in Google Map V3

Comment: If you provide some background about the `VEShape.GetIconAnchor` method, you will probably get some responses. What is `VEShape` and what work does the `GetIconAnchor` method perform?

Comment: May my bad English lead you wrong way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412408.aspx will give an idea about  GetIconAnchor

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to figure out exactly what you are asking, but I think you may be looking for one of:

- [google.maps.InfoWindow.getPosition()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)
- [google.maps.Marker.getPosition()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)
- [google.maps.MarkerImage.anchor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage) - the `MarkerImage` may be retrieved from a `Marker` by calling [google.maps.Marker.getIcon()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)